# Is there a way to create subdocuments of a document and make them communicate? [Database Design]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, database-design, shopify

I am building a Shopify App with Node.js I am pretty new to Shopify and this stuff. What I am supposed to do is:

- I have two stores, in UK and USA, but a single warehouse.
- Create products ( 10 x iPhone 11Pro with price of $900 ) and save it.
- After creation of products, I need to use the same source, from the same warehouses, but to offer them in USA and UK with different prices and different options. Basically, even though I have only 10 iPhones, I will show 10 in USA store and 10 in UK store available.

How can I create 20 iPhones (10 UK $800, 10 USA $850) different instances with discounts and other stuff from the warehouse that has only 10 iPhones to sell? What is the best approach?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the design you have planned so far? a schema perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If your warehouse exposes information via API just create a script that will fetch information about inventory quantity from your warehouse and will update it on both of your stores. Run it as often as you need to keep inventory levels in both stores up to date.

If your warehouse doesn't have API, create an application that will work based on **Order** or **InventoryLevel** [webhooks](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/notifications/webhooks). This will allow you to update inventory quantity in one store once order created/updated or inventory quantity changed for a product on the other store.

**Useful links:**

- [Manage product inventory with the Admin API](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-product-inventory-with-admin-api)
- [Webhooks API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook)